# postgresql text type to date

Tags: postgresql, date, types

so I am pretty new to this, but I would like to convert a text data_type into a date type (preferably into something like this yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ date/time with timezone).

Now, I have found the W3 page's  [convert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) 
and  [postresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html). I have also found some solutions on stack overflow, but they all didn't work.

I have queried my database like this

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE
FROM myappname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='myapp'
AND COLUMN_name LIKE '%date%'
ORDER BY table_name,column_name
```

where table_schema is where the tables of importance are in and table_name are tables of all my events. I selected only the properties (column_name) of these tables where they have a date, and all of them have a 'text' data_type.

Hence to my question, how can I convert them all to a date/time with timezone as above, so I can query my events (tables) by

```
where [column_name] between [date] and [date/time]
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You are looking for `to_date()`

Comment: Thank you for this input, but my problem is where would I put this code? Would I put it after `'COLUMN_name'`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to change the type of the table columns or do you want to compare a `text` column with a `date` in a query?

Comment: I would like to change the type of the table columns. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this for some time I found a solution. I am using 
`to_date()` as a_horse_with_no_name suggests.

I post this as this may help others. My date format in string looked like this:

Mon Feb 20 11:34:21 GMT+07:00 2017

by running the select code below I get a column named to_date with a date type that looks like

2017-02-20.

```
select to_date(column_name,'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS GMT+07:00 YYYY') from table_name;
```